# Changing the rownames of a dataframe 

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `t1` which has two fields `names` and `rollno`. I want to generate a data frame where the rownames are `names`. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
a <- data.frame(name=c("A", "B"), b=1:2)
b <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=1:2)
row.names(b) <- a$name
```